# Cannot match regex with re.search on Twisted Framework ircbot

Tags: python, irc, twisted.client

I'll start with "I'm not familiar with Python". I'm trying to change the default ircbot script from twisted for my channel, but I cannot get `re.match` or `re.search` working.

For example, this works:

```
prompt = ("%s" % self.nickname)
prompt1 = ("%s:" % self.nickname)
prompt2 = ("%s," % self.nickname)

if msg == (prompt1 + " whoareyou?") or msg == (prompt2 + " who are you?") or msg == (prompt1 + " whoareyou") or msg == (prompt2 + " who are you"):
```

This one as well

```
if msg == (prompt1 + " help") or msg == (prompt2 + " help"):
```

However these two conditions do not work on the bot (but they work on a local script):

```
if re.search(r'%s[:,] help' % self.nickname, msg):

elif re.search(r'%s[:,] who ?are ?you?' % self.nickname, msg):
```

A previous version of the script that is not using `re.search` can be found [here](https://github.com/mississaugalug/bash/commit/7a4fc9cb38fbb83fbbb08a52ff18a272ac3e5601)

Answer (score 0):

I have found what was causing the problem. Twisted included a logic to handle nickname collision for the bot. It adds a `^` at the end of the name:

```
# For fun, override the method that determines how a nickname is changed on
# collisions. The default method appends an underscore.
def alterCollidedNick(self, nickname):
    """
    Generate an altered version of a nickname that caused a collision in an
    effort to create an unused related name for subsequent registration.
    """
    return nickname + '^'
```

This was causing my bots nickname to end with `nickname^`, and because I used `%s` to add the nickname variable as part of the Regex, it interpreted the `^` as a modifier.

```
if re.search(r'%s[:,] help' % self.nickname, msg):
```

To this:

```
if re.search(r'nickname^[:,] help', msg):
```